# SlideUp callback doesn't add class to element

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I scroll the page I want to animate the header. It should `slideUp`, add a class and `slideDown`.

The `slideUp` and `slideDown` work as expected, however the class `header-small` isn't added. How come?

```js
$(function() {
  var moved = false,
      header = $('header');
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 20) {
      if (moved == 'false') {
        header.slideUp(500, function() {
          $(this).addClass('header-small').slideDown('slow');
        });
        moved = true;
      }
    } else {
      header.slideUp(500, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('header-small').slideDown('slow');
      });
      moved = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 300%;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 2em;
  background: lightblue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-small {
  font-size: .75em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  This is a header with text
</header>
```

I've tried changing `$(this)` to `$('header')`, but same result.

Comment: `'false'` string is truthly value in javascript, use `moved === false`   https://jsfiddle.net/fhqh1tx2/

Comment: Wow... that is the answer... thank you.

Comment: @A.Wolff, add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented string , should be boolean value without quotes like **false**

if (moved == **'false'**)